# Найти элемент по Xpath и Name в Selenium

Tags: python

Возможно ли как-то найти элемент по XPATH и NAME одновременно?

```
fields = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*/td[8]')
```

Допустим, есть такая строчка кода. Возможно ли как-то задать поиск сразу по двум тегам?

Comment: Для таких случаев в xpath 1.0 можно вот такие вещи `//*[self::h1 or self::h2]` и `//h1 | //h2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, вы можете использовать and или or в XPath, чтобы объединить различные критерии поиска. Например, чтобы найти элементы, которые имеют тег td и имя атрибута class равное my_class:

```
fields = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//td[@class="my_class"]')
```

Чтобы найти элементы, которые имеют тег td или тег th и имя атрибута class равное my_class:

```
fields = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//(td|th)[@class="my_class"]')
```

Помните, что нужно использовать круглые скобки чтобы обозначить группу элементов для объединения.